# how do you change some id or textlike the id of a textview everywhere in android studio

Tags: android

My problem is that when I have completed my app and then want to change the id of some textview I have to do it one by one everywhere in the main activity. Thats horrible ! Is there a way to just search and select all the Id's and change them altogether. I hope you guys understand.

Comment: nop you don't have too just select it then refractor and rename it. It'll change everywhere in the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highlight the item you want to rename, then click refactor -> rename